# Pass Column value as a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In Mysql, I am tring to find a way to pass a column value into a variable. Then use the variable as a table name in another query...Below is a MsSQL version of it, Please help me find a Mysql equivalent.

```
declare @tblname1 varchar(400)
set @tblname1=(SELECT companyname from companies where id=5)
exec(' SELECT sh.streetname FROM '+@tblname1+' sh WHERE sh.id IN (SELECT id from allstreets)')`  `
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

```
set @tblname1=(SELECT companyname from companies where id=5);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM CONCAT('SELECT sh.streetname FROM ', @tblname1, ' sh WHERE sh.id IN (SELECT id from allstreets)');
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Also, based on your question, I must say that creating a table for each companyname in the company table is a poor design and can only lead to frustration and disappointment.